# Creating multiple incarnations of akka persistent actor with different persistenceId?

Tags: actor, persistent-storage, recover, akka-persistence

My requirement is to design a eCommerce shopping cart using Akka Persistent actors .

My plan is to create a main Supervisor actor which receives all requests from UI and creates a new incarnation of a CartActor for every unique cart_id from the request .In such a way that each cart is represented by a unique persistent actor which maintains the cart state .

```
class CartActor extends PersistentActor{
  var cart :Cart = null
  override def receiveRecover: Receive = {
    case addSkutoCartEvent(cart_id :UUID, sku_id:String, price :BigDecimal) =>{
      addItemtoCart(cart_id,sku_id, price)
    }


  }

  override def receiveCommand: Receive = {

    case addSkuToCartCmd(cart_id , sku_id, price) => {

      addItemtoCart(cart_id,sku_id, price)
    }





  }
```

On a request to a particular cart i want to redirect the call to the specific actor to handle the processing ,i am doing this using the unique cart id as the name of the actor while creating it .

```
cartActor = system.actorOf(Props[CartActor],new_cart_id.toString)
```

and find the actor via

```
val future = system.actorSelection("/user/" + `cart_id.toString).resolveOne()`
```

The problem is the case where a actor was already created previously but is now terminated due to inactivity for some time , i'd want to recover it for a new request for the updates to that cart .I want to be able to recover that actor and pass this new request to it .
But as the CartActor is just one definition and has one unique persistent id for all incarnations ,how would i recover events for that particular cart actor representing that unique cart .Is there a way to set different persistent id for different incarnations of the same actor definition ?

Comment: for now i have kept the persistent id different for different incarnations .

Comment: I have used the cart id both as the name and the persistent id :
       system.actorOf(Props[CartActor],cart_id.toString)
and 
        override def persistenceId: String = self.path.name